# Advantage of Howling Helm in combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

My character has recently acquired an item called the Howling Helm. What I have been doing in some of the bigger encounters I've been in, is command the 1d3 Wolves it creates to attack before I do.

What benefit does this offer me when I go to attack? One of the guys who was watching us play said it was a good tactic, but I don't know why. **I was wondering if someone could explain what the benefits are of this tactic?**

Obviously, I may be able to flank - *if* I can get the wolves into position properly. What are the other benefits of having the wolves attack just before I do?

This is how the action takes place:

See foe, run towards them - (out of range), call wolves, new round, send wolves to attack, then I follow and attack.

Comment: It's good because wolves, man, _wolves_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's good because of [wolves'](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/wolf.html#_wolf) innate [trip](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/universalMonsterRules.html#_trip) ability.  If the wolves hit they can take a free trip attempt.  If they succeed the enemy is [prone](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#prone) and it makes it that much easier for you to hit them, and prevents them from moving without taking an attack of opportunity.

Comment: ahhh... that is very cool indeed!

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the points that C. Ross mentioned, the wolves acting first (specifically, moving) allows them to draw opportunity attacks from the monsters that you might normally have to take.

Answer (score 8):

Also, the wolves will spring any traps/obstacles that might be along the path before you do; a bit heartless, but Summon Monster I has always been a decent replacement for Find Traps for a reason.

Comment: This is an awesome idea!!! Its all good when they die they turn into snow and pinecones lol or something to that effect :P